# Python 3: request module - How to break session and continue?

Tags: python-3.x, timeout, python-requests

I am writing a web scraping program, and I am facing the following problem.
When my URL is *.doc or *.jpg, etc., my current request does not timeout and does not get passed to the next URL.

For example:

```
html = requests.get("http//:www.someweb.com/abcd.doc", verify=False, timeout=5)
```

can you help me on how to get() the url but some for like 10 seconds and then move to next one??

I have also tried with eventled:

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
with eventlet.Timeout(10):
    html = requests.get(enlance, verify=False)
```

and i received a bunch of errors as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "emailCrawler.py", line 69,
> in 
> getLinks("")   File "emailCrawler.py", line 64, in getLinks
> getLinks(page)   File "emailCrawler.py", line 64, in getLinks
> getLinks(page)   File "emailCrawler.py", line 64, in getLinks
> getLinks(page)   File "emailCrawler.py", line 64, in getLinks
> getLinks(page)   File "emailCrawler.py", line 64, in getLinks
> getLinks(page)   File "emailCrawler.py", line 25, in getLinks
> html = requests.get(enlance, verify=False)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py",
> line 72, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/api.py",
> line 58, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 508, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/sessions.py",
> line 618, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/adapters.py",
> line 440, in send
> timeout=timeout   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 601, in urlopen
> chunked=chunked)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
> line 357, in _make_request
> conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1107, in request
> self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1152, in _send_request
> self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1103, in endheaders
> self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 934, in _send_output
> self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 877, in send
> self.connect()   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 166, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py",
> line 141, in _new_conn
> (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py",
> line 73, in create_connection
> sock.connect(sa)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
> line 247, in connect
> self._trampoline(fd, write=True)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet/greenio/base.py",
> line 207, in _trampoline
> mark_as_closed=self._mark_as_closed)   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/**init**.py",
> line 163, in trampoline
> return hub.switch()   File "/home/ccnp/environments/my_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py",
> line 295, in switch
> return self.greenlet.switch() eventlet.timeout.Timeout: 10 seconds

Comment: You can use eventlet.Timeout(5) here which will be for 5 seconds

Comment: ive tried that, but it gives me a problem with some https

Comment: Can you post the code what you have tried and also the error please

Comment: i have added the code, thanks

Comment: Where are the errors ?

Comment: posted, they were not pasted in a formatted way, i dont know why

Comment: Your links from emailCrawler.py are not getting properly passed, your error is actually there

Comment: yes, but only when i use eventlet, if i dont use i dont get all those errors but get requesting forever when it finds .doc, .jpg, etc

Comment: requests.get("takes_only_url")

Comment: im scrapping all href in a website, so if it discovers a .doc as a link (href) it will request.get that .doc, or .pdf, etc and it will not timeout because the link is alive

Comment: why dont you write logic to ignore those stuff or something similar.

Comment: i did not want to write that, because you never know what you can find as a link in a website but i think i will do that, thanks any way

Comment: You never know the link I understand but the link hitting requests must always be a url.

Answer (score 0):

i think i have found the solution

instead of eventlet the request i eventlet the beautifulsoup like this

```
try:
    html = requests.get(enlance, verify=False, timeout=5)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    with eventlet.Timeout(5):
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "html.parser", from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
```